# Send user verification email from dart server

Tags: email, dart, email-validation, dart-server

I'm using Aqueduct to build a backend Dart server (but the answer doesn't have to use Aqueduct). When a new user signs up with an email address, I want to send a verification email to them. It will include a link back to the server, or possibly a verification code.

My problem is I don't know how to send an email in Dart. I didn't see any package on [Pub](https://pub.dev/packages?q=email) that looked like it would do it either.

Can I do it manually using `dart:io` or anything?

Comment: You shall use [mailer](https://pub.dev/packages/mailer) for that purpose

Comment: @Mattia, I missed that one. Thank you!

Comment: Someone else suggested using an saas email provider.